# how to draw polygon in google map in iOS, zip code wise in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding, core-location

i am working on map view where i have list of zip code and i want to highlight area of every zip code on map.
i am using google map.
i have list of zip code.
what i actually need is boundary coordinates of every zip code.

actual requirements are in picture.
[image]

```
CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"94111" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];

    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
    {
        // Process the placemark.
        CLLocation *location = aPlacemark.location;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

        NSLog(@"Latitude %f", coordinate.latitude);

        NSLog(@"Longitude %f", coordinate.longitude);

        [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)];
    }

    // Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
    GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
    polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.75];
    polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
    polygon.map = self.mapVew;


}];
```

Comment: Yeah, I also need to achieve this functionality. Please anyone help us.

Comment: yah i found help. what you have to do is list of latlong of boundary of each place in my case zipcode area. i found a csv file which contain all information.

Comment: can you please provide that csv file? Thanks @FaheemRajput

Comment: @Vibhooti sorry i left that company and the code was not in my PC. 
but the file contain by some US research organization who deals with gew related information.

Comment: This might help you. Please have a look into [this link](https://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code-map-boundary-data.asp)